# Find the minimum value of $(\sin x+ \csc x)^2 + (\sec x + \cos x)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I made it till $5+\tan^2x + \cot^2x$, but I don’t know how to proceed further.

Comment: Between this and your prior questions , it really looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: Seriously, it’s not my homework. I had problems listed out, and I posted the ones I couldn’t solve here. I even showed that I tried to solve it, and the AM.GM inequality hasn’t been taught to me yet, so ofc I could not solve it.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Yup, learning my way around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, by AM-GM
$$5+\tan^2x+\cot^2x\geq5+2=7.$$
The equality occurs for $\tan^2=\cot^2x,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

But for your problem we can use C-S:
$$\left(\sin{x}+\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\right)^2+\left(\cos{x}+\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\right)^2=5+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=$$
$$=5+(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)\geq5+2^2=9.$$
The equality occurs for $(\sin{x},\cos{x})||\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}},\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\right),$ which says that $9$ is a minimal value.

In  both problems for equality occurring we can take $x=45^{\circ}.$

In the first solution I used $$a^2+b^2\geq2ab,$$ which is just $$(a-b)^2\geq0,$$
for $a=\tan{x}$ and $b=\cot{x}.$

In the second solution I used
$$(a^2+b^2)\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)\geq4,$$ which is
$$2+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\geq4$$ or
$$a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2\geq0$$ or
$$(a^2-b^2)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: I couldn’t understand the equality part ie. the ending of the answer. Please clarify

Comment: @Aditya The equality occurs for $x=45^{\circ}.$

Comment: Is there another way to solve the question, without all these specific equalities?

Comment: @Aditya These inequalities are very easy thing. I'll add something. Wait please.

Comment: I really don’t want to irritate you, so if you feel that you should reply, it’s fine. However, I don’t think I am understanding the symbols and inequalities you used. Perhaps I am too dumb to understand it, and I do fine mathematics much more difficult than physics or chem, so an oversimplification would be nice. Again, you don’t need to reply if you don’t want to, as I feel I have troubled you enough.

Comment: @Aditya I am ready to help you. Ask please a concrete question.

Comment: Explain it to me like I am a 10 year old.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan^2x+\cot^2x=(\cot x-\tan x)^2+2\cot x\tan x\ge2$$  for real $\cot x-\tan x$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your function is $5+\tan^2x+\cot^2x$, actually. With $c:=\cos x,\,s:=\sin x$ your sum is $$\left(s+\frac{1}{s}\right)^2+\left(c+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2=5+\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}=5+\frac{1}{c^2s^2}=5+4\csc^22x\ge 9,$$with equality iff $\sin2x=\pm 1$, as occurs e.g. if $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ for which we get$$\left(s+\frac{1}{s}\right)^2+\left(c+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2=2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2=2\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=9.$$